# Connect I2C Oled via USB to Linux Box

Tags: usb, i2c, linux

I connected a **1.3" SH1106 Oled** via the I2C pins to a i2c-to-usb adapter (**UMFT201XB** from FTDI) and on my Linux Box (Z83 mini pc with Ubuntu 18.04) I can see the device under /dev/ttyUSB0.

This is the dmesg output:

```
[16123.056915] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[16123.212789] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6015
[16123.212806] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[16123.212816] usb 1-2: Product: UMFT201XB
[16123.212825] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[16123.212834] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: FTWCN8T5
[16123.216185] ftdi_sio 1-2:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[16123.216361] usb 1-2: Detected FT-X
[16123.216947] usb 1-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Now I want to write text/graphics to the OLED screen but I cannot find the i2c device with `i2cdetect -l`. After plugging in the USB, I don't see a extra device there (maybe there should not even be one?).

I use the `luma.oled` library on the Linux Box, but for the initialization, I need the i2c port and i2c address (somewhere in the docs they mention 0x22, but what port?).

**How can I find the port for the USB adapter**, if there is even one. I am a complete noob with i2c and virtual serial ports, so maybe my approach is completely wrong.

Comment: Your best bet is to probably spin your own interface using something like an Arduino connected to your display (via I2C).  Then use your pc over USB or Ethernet to talk to the Arduino.  You would need to write software for both the Arduino and your PC.  You should be able to find examples.    In modern hardware, and for various reasons, an I2C bus rarely leaves the inside of the enclosure (there are, of course, always exceptions, probably).  This is why one does not see PC's with "I2C ports".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not getting any reading from FTDI UMFT201XB USB-to-I2C module](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/39240/not-getting-any-reading-from-ftdi-umft201xb-usb-to-i2c-module) which explains the issue, the difference of host operating system is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a completely wrong chip for that job. It literally is an I2C to USB adapter, enabling USB via I2C bus. What you need USB to I2C adapter, which enables I2C via USB. FT201 is not a chip to be an I2C master to control slave I2C devices from PC. To the PC this chip looks like an USB serial port, and is an I2C slave chip to some other master device. This chip enables an a I2C master like a microcontroller, which otherwise has no USB connectivity, to communicate with a PC.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! What device exactly would you recommend? I cannot distinguish between a USB to I2C and a I2C to USB chip and the descriptions in the online shops are often vague

Comment: All the FTDI chips supporting [MPSSE](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE.htm) (FT2232D, FT2232H, FT4232H and FT232H) are candiates. On the Linux side, you would then create a program using FTDI's [libMPSSE](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/MPSSE/LibMPSSE-I2C.htm).

Comment: I have no knowledge which USB adapters would appear as I2C bus controller under Linux. The library is clearly meant to be run on a Raspberry Pi or similar board which already contains I2C bus controller for onboard chips and add-on boards. Maybe your PC has SMBus connector you can use? Also asking for recommendations what to buy is off topic on EE.SE.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I did read the datasheet and I have read it before. Please point to this information which states it can be used as I2C master. I found no such info, but I found info it can't be a master on many occasions. Website claims chip is I2C slave. Datasheet says it is USB I2C slave. I2C clock pin is input only. FT-X can't generate clock signal reads. Datasheet further emphasizes FT201X device can only be able to operate as a slave. It has a settable I2C address, like a slave would. Datasheet also points which chips should be used if I2C master is required.

Comment: So I got it to work with a ESP8266 chip which I programmed to receive the stuff I want to draw as a bitmap via the usb/serial port and then draw it via the o8g2 lib. Works seamlessly and is actually cheaper than using a USB->I2C adapter

Comment: Justme, No USB-I2C adapter will appear as "I2C device" in Linux/Win space. All devices of this sort will appear as one or another USB-class device -CDC or HID. The I2C side of the bridge is usually controlled by explicit specification of I2C address and data over some API interface, byte by byte, using vendor-supplied libraries that are specific to each particular USB-I2c bridge, FTDI, or Microchip, or SiLabs, etc. And yes, most of USB-I2C brides are I2C masters.